# How to open a multiples .py program

Tags: python, eclipse

I had a program (python 3.6) of one .py file (I think that is called script) that I used to code in python basic IDE 3.6, then I tried it in the shell and finally I used it making double clic in the .py file.  
Now, I met Eclipse (with PyDev) and now I code in this IDE. I learned that I can split my program into a few .py files to have the program more organized, and then I discover that I can have multiples packages with multiples .py files to have everything more organized.
Actually my program is:

```
Game
    /.settings                    # I didn't make it folder...
               /org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs          # ????
    /core                         # "main" package.
         /__pycache__               # I didn't make this folder but it have a lot of files that i used to use (put their are .pyc not .py). Can i delete them???
         /__init__.py               # I don't use it for now, but i read that all __init__.py files are very important... right?
         /main.py                   # This was my first file, for my this is the core, this file imports all the others, when i run the program in eclipse, i run this file. When the program was only a file, it was the file.
         /name_Data.csv             
         /registration.py           
    /functions                    # package with only functions (def)
              /__pycache__         
              /__init__.py
              /functions.py        
    /variables                    # package with only variables (config...)
              /__pycache__         
              /__init__.py
              /config.py           
              /variables.py        
    /.project                     # I didn't make it file...
    /.pydevproject                # I didn't make it file....
```

Also the folder Game is store in:

```
Workspace
         /Python
                /Game
                /.metadata        # ???
                          /.mylyn
                                 /.taskListIndex
                                                /segments.gen
                                                /segments_1
                                 /contexts
                                 /.task.xml.zip
                                 /repositories.xml.zip
                                 /task.xml.zip
                          /.plugins
                                    ... a lot of folders org.eclipse.jdt. etc...
                          /.back_0.log
                          /.lock
                          /.log
                          /version.init
```

Now when I test my code I always run it from eclipse (I don't use python IDE anymore), but this afternoon I tried to open the program making doble clic in main.py and it didn't work, also it didn't work in python IDE. When I made doble clic, it open a python console (sorry for my low knowledge, I think this is called Shell) for a second and close (without print nothing), when I open it in the python IDE it print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\####\Desktop\Extra\Workspace\Python\Game\core\main.py", line 25, in <module>
from variables import variables as var
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'variables'
```

How can I open it without Eclipse?
Also, shall I have the main.py file outside a package or in core package?

Comment: rightclick openwith > search for python executable.

Answer (score 0):

From variables.py import #the variables

That should do it. ( I think)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
from file1 import *
```

Example

var.py

```
x = "Hello"
```

main.py

```
from var import *

print(x)
```

When you run main.py it will print Hello

EDIT: After reading your error message more closely it would appear that is because the files live in different folders

To get around this on a project I just did yesterday

I had the following workspace

tests/

------> test.py

contactMetrics.py

To import contactMetrics.py I had to do the following

```
import os                                                                                    
import sys                                                                                   
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), os.pardir, os.pardir))
sys.path.append(path)

from ContactMetrics import ContactMetrics
```

Comment: I didn't use your method (it worked without using path), but reading your suggestion i have the idea of putthe main.py file outside the package and it works perfectly. Thanks anyway!!!